# How to deserialize Json file in c # to insert in table

Tags: c#, json, model

I have the following json and I am trying to deserialize to insert it into a SQL table, I have tried to use JsonConvert and JObject without positive result

**Json**

```
{
"id": "123123",
"publisherId": "Empresa",
"notificationType": "Orden",
"headers": {
    "providerId": "ABC123"
},
"content": {
    "id": "987987",
    "orderId": "4444444",
    "apiName": "Services",
    "method": "GetOrder",
    "verb": "GET",
    "urlMethod": "https://api.com"
},
"contentVersion": "1.0"
}
```

**Model**

```
    public class Headers
    {
        public string providerId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Content
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string orderId { get; set; }
        public string apiName { get; set; }
        public string method { get; set; }
        public string verb { get; set; }
        public string urlMethod { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootModel
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string publisherId { get; set; }
        public string notificationType { get; set; }
        public Headers headers { get; set; }
        public Content content { get; set; }
        public string contentVersion { get; set; }
    }
```

**Code**

```
    public static List<Models.RootModel> getJson()
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("c:\\LOG\\20180528\\201805281039.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.RootModel>(json);
        }
    }
```

You are giving me the following error

> Error CS0029  No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'WebApplication1.Models.RootModel' en 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I really do not know if I'm on the right track, is it necessary to deserialize to insert in the DB, or is there another way?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: I think you are on the right track, but your json file is an object, not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as the error states, it can not implicitly convert an instance of your model to a collection of your model.

You're trying to return a single instance:

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.RootModel>(json);
```

But your method is expecting to return a list of instances:

```
public static List<Models.RootModel> getJson()
```

If you're just returning one instance (since the JSON represents an object, not an array of objects), change your method to reflect that:

```
public static Models.RootModel getJson()
```

Answer (score 1):

*change your code*

```
public static Models.RootModel getJson()
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("c:\\LOG\\20180528\\201805281039.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.RootModel>(json);
        }
    }
```